# Legacy Media Queries and Device Pixel Ratio

Tags: css, media-queries

Will standard media queries such as:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 820px) {}
```

work on a device that is retina display?

I have read many articles on this, but most are about specifying the retina display css rather than how standard media queries developed for 96 dpi (the original size) will look on devices that have 300 dpi (retina display).

The main assurance I am looking for is: besides not taking full advantage of the quality being offered by the device, will the layout look the same if it was a 96dpi screen or 300dpi for example?

Much obliged for any help!

Comment: Media queries work fine on a device that is retina display. Retina pixel is not css pixel.

Comment: @Anon Thanks - so to confirm CSS pixel is expected to work across ALL devices - even until time immemorial (as far as we can currently tell)...?

Comment: http://www.howdesign.com/featured/hardware-css-pixels-retina-display/

Comment: Thanks for the link! It states in clear text: "Now consider this query:
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
Absent references to pixel density, it will target CSS styles to any iPad, with or without a Retina display, because it’s referring to CSS pixels, and in those terms the two are the same."

Answer (score 0):

CSS pixel is not hardware pixel. This [ARTICLE](http://www.howdesign.com/featured/hardware-css-pixels-retina-display/) explains the difference.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

Absent references to pixel density, it will target CSS styles to any iPad, with or without a Retina display, because it’s referring to CSS pixels, and in those terms the two are the same.

Comment: Yes I see that thanks, this is why I use min-width and max-width as seen in the question...the quote was taken from the article...the article also contradicts your statement however: "On a standard-resolution display, like the ones on most desktop and laptop computers, CSS pixels and hardware pixels are the same."